# Ordinals recursed

Tags: set-theory, ordinals

Consider any limit ordinal $\alpha$. It seems intuitively obvious to me that for any such ordinal there is $f:ORD \to ORD$ (with $ORD$ being the class of ordinals) with $f(1)=\alpha$ and $f$ preserving order.

Is this correct?

If that is the case. are there any relevant conclusions from this? What systems prove this for what ordinal $\alpha$?

Comment: Such a ‘function’ would be a proper class, so in $\mathsf{ZF(C)}$ one has to resort to a workaround in order to talk about it properly, but if you change that to the more natural $f(0)=\alpha$, your function is simply $f(\beta)=\alpha+\beta$ (ordinal addition).

Comment: The first ordinal is $0$. Let $f(0)=\alpha$ and then, as @BrianM.Scott shows, $f$ has a simple description. It would seem that any system proves this for any $\alpha$ it can prove to exist, as long as the system is closed under ordinal $+$. It depends on what you mean by "system".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving aside for a moment the issues with class functions, here's an easy definition of such an $f$ for any $\alpha$:

- $f(0)=0$,
- $f(1+\beta)=\alpha+\beta$ for all $\beta\in ON$.

This $f$ is extremely easy to formally define, as long as we can make sense of ordinal addition: it is defined by the formula $$f(\alpha)=\gamma\iff (\alpha=0\wedge \gamma=0)\vee \exists \beta<\alpha(\alpha=1+\beta\wedge \gamma=\alpha+\beta).$$ Any theory capable of proving even very basic facts about ordinals shows that this formula defines a total function; and if we're working in a class theory, then a very small amount of class comprehension proves that this function exists.